# Docbook to HTML conversion tools (other than jade)

Tags: html, docbook

Are there any alternative tools for the conversion of Docbook documents (V4 or V5) to (X)HTML other than the standard Jade tool and the associated DSSSL stylesheet?. Of course XSLT is an option. I am looking for something more robust and handy compared to Jade (which is outdated technology).

Comment: Yes, XSLT is the way to go. See http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/index.html.

Answer (score 2):

I have got good results with the (XSLT based) following ones:

- Maven plugin:

  - docbkx-maven-plugin
  - maven-jdocbook-plugin
- Publican

Answer (score 1):

The only options known to me for converting DocBook to HTML are DSSSL and XSLT.  XSLT is the standard nowadays.  I don't know what you hope to get from some other tool.